# I have a draggable image and when I drop it out of an overflow/scrollable area the click function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a scrolling div that has images inside of it. I drag the image outside of the scrolling area and drop it onto another area.
When I drop it onto the area I want to record the x and y value for where the image is and use an ajax call to record it to a database. At the moment I am able to get the x and y in an alert when it is dropped but it doesn't save it when it drops. It will save to the database when I click the image after I place it onto the area.

```
    $('.dragthis').draggable({
        cursor: 'pointer',
            revert: "invalid" ,
            helper: function(){
                $copy = $(this).clone();
               return $copy;},
            appendTo: 'body',
            scroll: false
     });

    $("#dragarea").droppable({
        accept:  '.dragthis',
        hoverClass: 'hover',
        tolerance: 'touch',
        drop: function(event, ui){

            if (ui.draggable.hasClass('dragthis')) {
            $(this).append(ui.draggable); ui.draggable.css('top', ui.position.top);
                ui.draggable.css('left', ui.position.left);
                ui.draggable.css('position', 'absolute');
                ui.draggable.draggable('destroy').draggable();  
            }

            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var relativeX = (event.pageX - offset.left); 
            var relativeY = (event.pageY - offset.top);
            alert("X: " + relativeX + "  Y: " + relativeY);

            $('img').click(function(){
                var name = $(this).attr('src');
                alert(name);

            $.ajax({
                method:"POST",
                url:"set.php",
                data: ({xValue: relativeX,  yValue: relativeY, nameValue: name}),
             });

            });
        }
     });
```

Comment: First check your ajax payload that is sent from your browser if the values sent match your alert. After that check you database. After that verify in your browser that you receive the same values from your server.

Comment: When I drag the image the alert shows the x and y values and then I have to click the image a second time to do the click. I want it to be all one motion where once you drop it it will get the x and y then it posts to the DB . But it makes me click it a second time. http://imgur.com/a/aofJK